# How to make a MySQL column value equal a variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have in my database a column called counter, i'm trying to save one of the rows of that column into a variable in PHP and make it equal the column rating. I do not want to make it from sql directly, I need to make it through php.
The problem is that when I run the query, the value for rating does not change at all. Please give me a solution

```
$cntrvalue = "SELECT counter FROM schools WHERE name = 'School1'";
$cntrResult = $this->conn->query($cntrvalue);
$mys1 = "UPDATE schools SET  rating = $cntrResult WHERE name = 'School1'";
$this->conn->query($mys1);
```

Thanks

EDIT:

Sorry the code above gives an error, this is the code that changes nothing

```
    $cntrvalue = "SELECT counter FROM schools WHERE name = 'School1'";
$this->conn->query($cntrvalue);
$mys1 = "UPDATE schools SET  rating = $cntrvalue WHERE name = 'School1'";
$this->conn->query($mys1);
```

EDIT 2:
What i'm trying to do now is that i'm trying to get the value of a SUM query:

```
$mys4 = "SELECT SUM(`s1`+`s2`*2 +`s3`*3 + `s4`*4 + `s5`*5) FROM schools WHERE name = 'School1'";
$mys4Result = $this->conn->query($mys4);
    $mys4Value = $mys4Result->fetch_assoc()[''];
```

The thing is that there is no column in the db to fetch from for this operation. What am I supposed to do? Thanks

Comment: try `rating = '$cntrResult' `

Comment: @A.ANoman didn't work :(

Comment: `$cntrResult` is the resultset, not the actual value.... you need to fetch the result and get the value from that

Comment: See about JOINs

Comment: @MarkBaker isn't the mysql_fetch_object function depreciated? Can I still use it?

Comment: No you shouldn't use `mysql_fetch_object()`, the whole `mysql` interface is depreacted, not just specific functions; you should be using mysqli or pdo, but they have equivalents to fetch results from a resultset. or the resultset is iterable, so you can use a foreach

Answer (score 1):

Want you want to achieve, can be done within one mysql query, but if you just want how to fix that code:

You need to use the $cntrResult outside the string. Try string concatenation.

First you need to make sure, you have the correct value, as $cntrResult is not an string object, its an resultset:

```
$value = $result->fetch_assoc()['counter']
```

And the query:

```
"UPDATE schools SET  rating = '" . $value . "' WHERE name = 'School1'";
```

Comment: make sure, you don't forgot one of the ' / ", if it doesn't you may print / echo the $value to check, narrow down the error surface.

Comment: @PatrickPirker Sir, i'm trying to do the same thing for another piece of code. But this time what I'm selecting is not a column, but a SUM:  SELECT SUM(`s1`+`s2`*2 +`s3`*3 + `s4`*4 + `s5`*5) FROM schools WHERE name = 'School1'    how can I do the same thing above for this? I tried implementing it the same way but no luck. The thing is that for the function fetch_assoc()['']; there is no actual column to select. What should I do?

Comment: @SaudAbdelaziz Your enthusiasm is appreciated, but as best as I can tell, the SELECT is completely redundant.

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean, i'm a beginner at PHP